# Get `LayoutBounds` height and width from static resource in .NET MAUI

Tags: maui, resourcedictionary, absolutelayout

I have the following XAML:

```xml
<Path Style="{StaticResource squared}"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="-.2, .2, .3, .3" />

<Path  Style="{StaticResource squared}"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1.1, .7, .3, .3" />

<Path Style="{StaticResource squared}"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="-.1, .9, .3, .3" />
```

Since the height and width are the same, I was trying to set them via a static resource.

```xml
<x:Decimal x:Key="SquareSize">.3</x:Decimal>
```

However, I don't see a way to use it and pass only the height and width. I have tried something like this:

```xml
<AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds>
    <Rect>
        <Rect.X>-.2</Rect.X>
        <Rect.Y>.2</Rect.Y>
        <!--No way to assign a static resouce below--> 
        <Rect.Height />
        </Rect>
</AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds>
```

Answer (score -1):

`AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds` needs a `Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle` object.

You can refer to the following code:

```
        <x:Double x:Key="myWidth">100</x:Double> 
        <x:Double x:Key="myHeight">100</x:Double>

        <Rectangle x:Key="mRectangle" 
                   WidthRequest="{StaticResource myWidth}"      
                   HeightRequest="{StaticResource myHeight}"
               > 
        </Rectangle>
```

And bind it as follows:

```
    <Frame  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="{Binding mRectangle}" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" BackgroundColor="Yellow">
        
    </Frame>
```

Comment: This is on Xamarin. I was asking about MAUI. In MAUI, it requires the `Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Rect` mentioned in the question which does not have such bindable properties.

Comment: Above code can also been used in maui. The usage is similar.

Comment: Not really. Thats what I had explained in the comment above. The `Rect` class in maui doesn't have any bindable properties I could bind `{StaticResource myHeight}` to